# container_of macro when we have a pointer inside a struct

Tags: c, linux, pointers, struct, kernel

If I have:

```
struct my_container {
    int x;
    struct some_struct *ss;
}
```

If I have the pointer ss through which I can access the members inside some_struct, I should be able to access my_container by doing the following right ? 
This is what I am doing:

```
struct my_container *my_c;
my_c = container_of(&ss, struct my_container, ss)
```

But this is not working for sure and I am not able to comprehend why.
Can someone help me with this? Is there something that I am missing ?

Comment: what do you mean by container_of() is it a used defined function?

Comment: @Madan it's a macro in the linux kernel that acts as the "inverse" of `offsetof`

Comment: Is container_of something like #define container_of(ptr, type, member) ((type *)((char *)(ptr)-(unsigned long)(&((type *)0)->member)))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only have a pointer to `some_struct` (i.e. if you *just* have `struct some_struct *ss;`), you cannot use the `container_of` macro in this way, as `&ss` will just evaluate to the address of some variable, **not** the address of `my_container`. To use it properly, you'll need a pointer to a pointer to `some_struct` (i.e. `struct some_struct **pss`).

Comment: Ok. I understand what I am doing wrong. Thank you!
But the problem I have right now is, for getting the pointer to some_struct I am using container_of() macro. I am not sure how would I be able to get the pointer to a pointer to some_struct. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It means that instead of using struct my_container *my_c; my_c = container_of(&ss, struct my_container, ss); you would use: struct some_struct **my_struct_ptr = &some_struct_ptr; my_c = container_of(&my_struct_ptr, struct my_container, ss); .The first parameter of container_of is the address to start from, NOT the pointer within your struct. Hope this helps

Comment: @buzz I think you meant struct some_struct **my_struct_ptr = &some_struct_ptr; my_c = container_of(my_struct_ptr, struct my_container, ss);